# Does `--link-dest` of `rsync` only take an absolute pathname?

Tags: rsync, filenames

Is it true that `--link-dest=DIR` of `rsync` only take an absolute pathname for `DIR`, and relative pathname for `DIR` doesn't work?

When I run

```
rsync -a --delete --link-dest=dest my\ dir  dest2/
rsync -a --delete --link-dest=./dest my\ dir  dest2/
```

identical files in source `my\ dir` and `dest` or `./dest` are copied into destination directory `dest2`.

When I run

```
rsync -a --delete --link-dest=/tmp/test/backup/dest my\ dir  dest2/
```

identical files in source `my\ dir` and `/tmp/test/backup/dest`  are hard linked from `/tmp/test/backup/dest` to destination directory `dest2`

---

If my guess is true, then how is `rsync` implemented to take only an absolute path for `--link-dest`?

Is it correct that all the functions in Linux API, if they take pathname arguments, their pathnames arguments can be either of absolute and relative pathnames?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting [the `rsync` manpage](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html)’s description of `--link-dest`:

> If *DIR* is a relative path, it is relative to the destination directory.

Thus you can use relative paths, relative to the destination directory.

I’m not sure what the “Linux API” (I’m guessing you’re referring to the userspace API provided by the kernel) has to do with this, `rsync` isn’t a Linux-specific tool. However, most if not all calls which accept paths can take absolute and relative pathnames; in the latter case, the paths are usually relative to the current directory or to a provided file descriptor (in the `...at` calls, *e.g.* [`openat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)). (I haven’t checked *all* the calls.)

Comment: Thanks. "I’m not sure what the “Linux API” (I’m guessing you’re referring to the userspace API provided by the kernel) has to do with this". On Linux, isn't rsync implemented based on Linux API?

Comment: Ultimately yes, `rsync` on Linux is *implemented* on top of the Linux API (like any program running on Linux). However I don’t think it was *designed* on top of the Linux API, and it’s not developed on top of the Linux API — it’s designed with a certain feature set, and developed using the C standard library.

Comment: Thanks for clarifcation. (1) I can't find `openat` in the standard C library. Is `openat` in Linux API only?  What function in the standard C library does `rsync` call explicitly in place of `openat`? (2) What are other `...at calls` besides `openat` in either Linux API or the C standard library?

Comment: [`openat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/openat.html) is defined [by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/functions.html); note that I only gave that as an example of functions taking a file descriptor for the base of relative paths, `rsync`’s `--link-dest` doesn’t use anything like that. The other `...at` functions are `faccessat`, `fchownat`, `fstatat`, `linkat`, `mkdirat`, `mkfifoat`, `mknodat`, `readlinkat`, `renameat`, `symlinkat`, and `unlinkat`.

Comment: Thanks. Wondering how you found the *at functions? Can I grep it somewhere?

Comment: Look at the second link in my previous comment...